# VS Code Controls not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue in VS Code. By mistake, I clicked some options and my VS Code looks like this now. It is not showing the menu and cannot be minimized either. Can someone please help me out to restore the VS Code in its default format.

[image: description]

Comment: Press F11. It's the fullscreen mode

Answer (score 0):

Full Screen mode:
[image]

Press the `ALT` key and the toolbar will show up:

[image]

Exit Full Screen mode with F11:
[image]